# WebGL/GLSL vertex shader collapses 9 points into single point when I set x coord of gl_Position to zero

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, webgl, vertex-shader

I do not understand why the following two shaders produce different results when I render a vertex buffer with x coordinates equal to zero:

First:

```
attribute vec3 position;

void main() {
  gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Second:

```
attribute vec3 position;

void main() {
  gl_Position = vec4(0.0, position.y, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

The result of the first is a line of nine dots. The result of the second is a single dot.

I'm drawing the following vertex array as GL_POINTS:

```
0.0, -1.00, 0.0,
0.0, -0.75, 0.0,
0.0, -0.50, 0.0,
0.0, -0.25, 0.0,
0.0,  0.00, 0.0,
0.0,  0.25, 0.0,
0.0,  0.50, 0.0,
0.0,  0.75, 0.0,
0.0,  1.00, 0.0
```

Here's the VBO preparation calls:

```
var a = new Float32Array([
    0.0, -1.00, 0.0,
    0.0, -0.75, 0.0,
    0.0, -0.50, 0.0,
    0.0, -0.25, 0.0,
    0.0,  0.00, 0.0,
    0.0,  0.25, 0.0,
    0.0,  0.50, 0.0,
    0.0,  0.75, 0.0,
    0.0,  1.00, 0.0
]);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, b);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, a.byteLength, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, a);
```

Here's the draw calls:

```
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, b);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(p.position, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(p.position);
gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 9);
```

Comment: What happens with, say, "gl_Position = vec4(0.05, position.y, 0.0, 1.0);"? And have you tried multiple browsers? GLSL compilers tend to treat values like 0.0, 0.5 and 1.0 as special cases and often attempt to build special case code. It's possible your browser's GLSL compiler has some sort of obscure bug — the two vertex shaders look like they should do the same thing in your case.

Answer (score 1):

That is a known problem (sorry, no link for now).

Basically, GLSL compiler thinks that attribute 'position' is not used, because the first component of it is not used. To check this try the following test:

```
gl_Position = vec4(0.0, position.y, 0.0, 1.0) + position.x*0.001;
```

Once you confirm the bug, you can either update you video driver or use an obvious workaround.